# mv: cannot move 'DVWA-master' to '/var/www/html/DVWA-master': Permission denied

Tags: permissions, mv

```
$ mv DVWA-master /var/www/html
mv: cannot move 'DVWA-master' to '/var/www/html/DVWA-master': Permission denied
```

How can I fix it?

I want to move a folder in `/var/www/html`.

Answer (score 2):

The meaning of the error is:

The user which execute the `mv` command doesn't have write permission to the folder `/var/www/html`

If you need to move a file or a folder to the `/var/www/html/` folder, and you have `sudo` permissions, you'll be able to do it using:

```
sudo mv DVWA-master /var/www/html
```

Answer (score 0):

Do

```
sudo mv DVWA-master /var/www/html
```

and check  the permission of the  main folder with :

```
ls -l /var/www/html
```

and

```
ls -l /var/www
```

As you put data  in the `www`  folder, I'm thinking that could be the folder of apache content. So, you should to apply a `chown` for get the apache application access to the new sub folder `DVWA-master`.